# Conditional Bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I have this very simple Javascript code:

```js
$("#myinput").hover(function(){
    if(condition){
        $(this).tooltip({placement: "bottom", title: "mytitle"}); 
    }
);
```

with its HTML:

```html
<input data-toggle="tooltip" type="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" id="myinput" name="password" required />
```

When I load the page the condition it's false so the tooltip correctly doesn't show and when it becomes true it starts showing. The problem is that when the condition goes back to false the tooltip keeps showing when hovering even if it shouldn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: This is because you have a condition to set the tool tip if true, once it is true, then it is set. If the condition then becomes false, then the setting of the tooltip is skipped, and does nothing, which is why the tooltip remains. Once the condition is false, you need code to remove or hide the tool tip from the dom. :)

Comment: I've tried adding `$(this).tooltip('disable')` or `$(this).tooltip('hide')` in the else bracket but this way the tooltip never shows, even if the condition is true @Brent

Comment: The reason it doesn't work if it is true is because you have errors. Programmers don't just guess on things like "disable" or "hide". You should look up how to close a tool tip or hide it from the page by going to bootstrap's website and looking at the documentation

Comment: I don't know why you think I am trying to guess it, bootstrap documentation actually talks about both the methods. 'Hide' -> "Hides an element’s tooltip", 'disable' -> "Removes the ability for an element’s tooltip to be shown". Adding `$(this).tooltip('enable')` didn't work too. If you don't know the answer just stop replying :) @Brent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add an else statement for your false condition and call `$(this).tooltip("dispose");` to get rid of the tooltip. Otherwise tooltip will always be enabled.

Bootstrap 5 documentation on [#dispose](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#dispose) and all its tooltip [methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#methods).

Small demo of toggling tooltip.

```js
let condition = true;

$("#myinput").hover(function () {
    if (condition) {
        $(this).tooltip({ placement: "bottom", title: "mytitle" });
    } else {
        $(this).tooltip("dispose");
    }
});

const button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    condition = !condition;
    if (condition) {
        button.textContent = "Turn Tooltip Off";
    } else {
        button.textContent = "Turn Tooltip On";
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-toggle="tooltip" type="password" 
       placeholder="Enter your Password" 
       id="myinput" name="password" 
       required />


<button id="button">Turn Tooltip Off</button>
```